# Visual Studio - Find in files > not any node_modules folders

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, node-modules, findinfiles

So in Visual Studios you can "Find in files" a string - I find this very useful to locate a file in which some markup or JS may be found, I use VS for my main code editor for Web development.

The problem is, most of my projects use node.js and node based build tools grunt/gulp etc. so I have a node_modules folder somewhere in my project that makes the FIND take for ever as there are thousands of files!!

How can I search in files and folders for a string BUT not in a node_modules directory.

In SublimeText2 you can remove a folder from the project without deleting it, this will stop a search looking in there...

A RegExp will be for the string not the filePath :(

Comment: Can you exclude the node_modules folder from the project?  Alternatively can you hide the node_modules folder (do they have a common root), by setting the Hidden attribute on the folder?

Comment: That's a good idea, it stops Visual Studio searching inside & doesn't stop Grunt from running. - would need to test this idea running a node server and gulp.

I don't mind making the folder hidden on each project a fairly small change to stop irritation and increase #velocity

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ok so I've tried this and it seems to work.

You can hide the node_modules folder (if they have a common root), by setting the Hidden attribute on the folder.  As you say it fulfils your needs as per the question.

Comment: Thanks @alergy, adding the hidden attribute on the node_module directory worked for me.  However, I also had to refresh the solution explorer for the search to actually exclude the hidden directory.

Answer (score 2):

**2020 Version**

Add the following exclusion

```
!*\node_modules\*;!*\bin\*;!*\obj\*;!*\.*
```

[image]